# my for loop isn't working properly in javascript . it is iterating for less amount than it should

Tags: javascript, html, loops, for-loop

my for loop should have 7 iterations but it tends to have different no if iterations some times its 5 some 4 some 3

this is my javascript code

```
var start = new Date().getTime();
var end = new Date().getTime();

function timeTaken(start1, end1) {
  return ((end1 - start1) / 1000);
}

function appear() {
  document.getElementById("shape").style.display = "block";
  start = new Date().getTime();

}

function delay() {
  setTimeout(appear, Math.random() * 7000);
}
//        delay();

function gameStart() {
  for (var i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    delay();

    document.getElementById("shape").onclick = function() {
      end = new Date().getTime();
      document.getElementById("shape").style.display = "none";
      document.getElementById("time-taken").innerHTML = timeTaken(start, end) + "s";
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: what are you trying to do?

Comment: can you add relevant html code

Comment: That for loop, which has eight iterations, runs all eight of them in the first millisecond. Within the following seven seconds, all eight timeouts will trigger at various points in time. Clicking the shape will run the event handler function eight times. At the point when you click the shape for the first time, `appear` might have already been called more than once, which is why you think you get less iterations. However the loop is no longer running at all.

Comment: JS is event based, so you need to move on to the next step after the timeout elapses or the user has interacted with the page: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/3bnjzp70/

Answer (score 0):

If you declare variable with `var`, problem can occupay, because you use `setTimeOut`, you must use `let`.

> `let` allows you to declare variables that are limited in scope to the
> block, statement, or expression on which it is used. This is unlike
> the `var` keyword, which defines a variable globally, or locally to an
> entire function regardless of block scope.

Below is a simple code snippet which should console log out the value of i after 100ms on each loop.

```
for(var i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
   setTimeout(function() {
       console.log('Value of i : ' + i); 
   },100);
}
```

The desired output of the above code is:

```
Value of i : 1
Value of i : 2
Value of i : 3
Value of i : 4
Value of i : 5
```

But the actual output is:

```
Value of i : 6
Value of i : 6
Value of i : 6
Value of i : 6
Value of i : 6
```

The above result is because, `var` defines variable globally, or locally to an entire function regardless of block scope.

With the introduction of `let` which defines the variable in block scope, the above code can be refactored as shown below

```
for(let i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
   
   setTimeout(function(){
       console.log('Value of i : ' + i);
   },100);
}
```

Output:

```
Value of i : 1
Value of i : 2
Value of i : 3
Value of i : 4
Value of i : 5
```

See more : https://medium.com/front-end-developers/es6-variable-scopes-in-loops-with-closure-9cde7a198744

Answer (score 0):

So as far as I understand you are looking for a way to call something x times with a timeout and it seems as you want to have some game logic with it.

This might overshoot by quite a bit....
The event handler has to be bound only once since its trigerd on click, so keep it out of the loop.

As for the loop you want can either use setInterval or Promises or recursion. I opted for recursion since it is quite easy in this case since you want to call a loop for x times. Now with JS running asynchronous you wont know when the recursion will end since it can be x deep so I included a Promise chain to return the results and give you the option to do something with the results.

```
// event handler for click
document.getElementById("shape").onclick = function () {
    end = new Date().getTime();
    document.getElementById("shape").style.display = "none";
    // using innerText instead of inner HTML, read MDN if you want to know why
    document.getElementById("time-taken").innerText = `${(end - start) / 1000}s`;
    // pushing result to array for results
    result.push((end - start) / 1000)

}

// declarations
let start, end;
let result = [];

function play(rounds) {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        // checking if another roud should be played
        if (rounds <= 0) {
            // setting last round timer
            console.log(`play time is up starting last round`)
            setTimeout(()=>{
                // hidding the element when done
                document.getElementById("shape").style.display = "none";
                // resolving for results
                resolve(result)
            }, Math.random() * 7000)

        } else {
            // statrting timeout if round should be played
            setTimeout(() => {

                // setting start when square will be displayed
                start = new Date().getTime();
                // showing html element
                document.getElementById("shape").style.display = "block";
                // starting the next round --> user therefore has Math.random()*7000 to click the element
                // after the other timer runs out start will be reset
                resolve(play(rounds - 1))

            }, Math.random() * 7000)

        }

    })
}
// calling the play function 5 times
play(5).then(res => console.log(res))
```

Comment: Thanks for the ans it was helpfull. I understood what your code. I even out the onclick function outside like you said. I still don't understand why the loop didn't work.

Comment: ok, JS is asynchronous, which means that if you call multiple functions they will execute in parallel. Try to call 2 setTimeout functions with different timeouts that just log something to the console.

What happend in your case was that the program entered the loop, called delay, called the rest and ran the next loop. It didn't wait for delay because Honey Badger doesn't care. What you saw on your screen where the 7 setTimeout running in parallel.

Comment: for any one want to check out a timer with intervals, which would be a similar problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59478991/cleartimeout-not-working-parameter-undefinedeven-though-its-defined-in-the-gl/59480788#59480788